# bootstrap class to provide vertical spacing for rows of a table?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, cellspacing

I use bootstrap 3 grid system as the following

```
   <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-4 ">label1:</div>
    <div class="col-md-6"> {{{  $value1 }}} </div>
  </div>
   <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-4 " >label2:</div>
    <div class="col-md-6"> {{{  $value2 }}} </div>
  </div>
```

but rows are very tight together and I need some vertical spacing between two adjacent rows.
I know `form-group` class works for forms, I look for such a class for rows of table or I should use `form-group`?

Comment: Are you talking about the vertical spacing? Generally that's covered by putting the relevant tags around the content such as form-group, label, or whatever is going in those columns, otherwise you would create a custom class and add some bottom margin.

Comment: yes vertical spacing between rows, I know form-group is for forms, I asked for a bootstrap class in such occasions!

Answer (score 1):

A more semantic structure would be to use Bootstrap's horizontal description lists.

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
  <dt>label1:</dt>
  <dd> {{{  $value1 }}} </dd>
  <dt>label2:</dt>
  <dd> {{{  $value2 }}} </dd>
</dl>
```

They have the added advantage of auto-truncating the description with an ellipsis (...) if the  description becomes too long to display.

**Bootstrap CSS docs:**
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-lists
(and scroll down to *Horizontal description*).